# Can I use android phone for arm development?

Tags: arm, android

Android phones are mostly run over ARM processors. In Pakistan purchasing an ARM development board is very difficult and almost not available. Importing from other country cost it a lot. 
On the other hand Android phones are very cheap as for just 25$ to 30$ so I was wondering can we use android phones as ARM Development like? If so, then Is there any starting point available over web? I searched google but did not find any useful information. Any body have experienced it before? please share
thanks

Comment: You can compile ARM code on a PC, and you can run it on a (rooted!) Android phone - but at some point you want an actual physical ARM device?

Comment: any example or basic idea behind it?